# How to select parent that contains certain children from his ManyToMany relation?

Tags: python, sql, django-orm, tortoise-orm

Given this piece of code **(Python & TortoiseORM)**:

```
class Recipe(Model):
    description = fields.CharField(max_length=1024)
    ingredients = fields.ManyToManyField(model_name="models.Ingredient", on_delete=fields.SET_NULL)


class Ingredient(Model):
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=128)
```

How to query all recipes that contain BOTH Ingredient.name="tomato" and Ingredient.name="onion" ?
I believe that in Django-ORM it was possible to make some intersection of QuerySets using & operator or intersect method.

**Update #1**
This query worked but it's a bit messy in my opinion and it's gonna be problematic when I will want to f.e. query all recipes that contain more than 2 ingredients.

```
subquery = Subquery(Recipe.filter(ingredients__name="onion").values("id"))  
await Recipe.filter(pk__in=subquery , ingredients__name="tomato")
```

**Update #2**

```
SELECT "recipe"."description",
       "recipe"."id"
FROM   "recipe"
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "recipe_ingredient"
                    ON "recipe"."id" = "recipe_ingredient"."recipe_id"
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "ingredient"
                    ON "recipe_ingredient"."ingredient_id" = "ingredient"."id"
WHERE  "ingredient"."name" = 'tomato'
       AND "ingredient"."name" = 'onion'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Recipe.objects.filter(
    ingredients__name='tomato'
).filter(
    ingredients__name='onion'
)
```

By using two [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) calls, we make *two* `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s, one where we search for `tomato`, and one for `onion`. This apparently only works with the Django ORM, not the Tortoise ORM.

If we use `print(qs.query)` (to construct the query), we obtain:

```
SELECT recipe.id, recipe.description
FROM recipe
INNER JOIN recipe_ingredients ON recipe.id = recipe_ingredients.recipe_id
INNER JOIN ingredient ON recipe_ingredients.ingredient_id = ingredient.id
INNER JOIN recipe_ingredients T4 ON recipe.id = T4.recipe_id
INNER JOIN ingredient T5 ON T4.ingredient_id = T5.id
WHERE ingredient.name = tomato
  AND T5.name = onion
```

Another option is to make a *single* `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, and check if the number of items matches with the number of items, so:

```
from django.db.models import Count

items = {'tomato', 'onion'}

Recipe.objects.filter(
    ingredients__name__in=items
).alias(
    ncount=Count('ingredients')
).filter(ncount=len(items))
```

or prior to [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2):

```
from django.db.models import Count

items = {'tomato', 'onion'}

Recipe.objects.filter(
    ingredients__name__in=items
).annotate(
    ncount=Count('ingredients')
).filter(ncount=len(items))
```

this thus provides a query that looks like:

```
SELECT recipe.id, recipe.description
FROM recipe
INNER JOIN recipe_ingredients ON recipe.id = recipe_ingredients.recipe_id
INNER JOIN ingredient ON recipe_ingredients.ingredient_id = ingredient.id
WHERE ingredient.name IN (onion, tomato)
GROUP BY recipe.id
HAVING COUNT(recipe_ingredients.ingredient_id) = 2
```

Especially the `HAVING COUNT(recipe_ingredients.ingredient_id)` is key here, since the `WHERE` clause already filtered this down to only onions and tomatos.

This requires that the `name` of the ingredients is unique (i.e. there are no two `Ingredient` records with the same name). You can make the `name` field unique with:

```
class Ingredient(Model):
    name = fields.CharField(unique=True, max_length=128)
```

Comment: I've tried the first one but it generated one query with "WHERE ingredients.name = 'tomato' AND ingredients.name = 'onion'". I don't know if it's not a problem of this TortoiseORM...

Comment: @Rechu: This is only the case if you do this in the *same* `.filter(..)` call, if you use *separate* `.filter(...)` calls, it will make *two* `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s. You thus should ***not*** filter with `.filter(ingredients__name='tomato', some_other_filter)`.

Comment: I've tried to make it using chained filters as you said in the first code block. However i still got an empty list as a result. You can find the query that it produced in Update #2.

Comment: @Rechu: if you `print(qs.query)` then it prints the query behind the queryset, for the first queryset, it returns:

Comment: ```SELECT `app_name_recipe`.`id`, `app_name_recipe`.`description` FROM `app_name_recipe` INNER JOIN `app_name_recipe_ingredients` ON (`app_name_recipe`.`id` = `app_name_recipe_ingredients`.`recipe_id`) INNER JOIN `app_name_ingredient` ON (`app_name_recipe_ingredients`.`ingredient_id` = `app_name_ingredient`.`id`) INNER JOIN `app_name_recipe_ingredients` T4 ON (`app_name_recipe`.`id` = T4.`recipe_id`) INNER JOIN `app_name_ingredient` T5 ON (T4.`ingredient_id` = T5.`id`) WHERE (`app_name_ingredient`.`name` = tomato AND T5.`name` = onion)```

Comment: @Rechu: exactly what backend do you use, and what Django version?

Comment: As you can see in the description's first sentence, i'm not using Django, i'm using Tortoise-ORM which was based on Django-ORM

Comment: @Rechu: in that case you should probably use the count-solution (second code fragment), since then we only need a single `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: I think that 2nd option wont work when Recipe has f.e Tomato and Orange in it.

Comment: @Rechu: it will return the `Recipe` if it has at least `Tomato` and `Onion`, the other ingredients do not matter.

Comment: doesnt this "__in" works as SQL "in" operator? If so than it will return the Recipe that has Tomato or Onion

Comment: @Rechu: exactly, but then we *count* the number of ingredients that satisfied this filter, and if there are *two* such `Ingredient`s, we know that *both* the `Tomato` or the `Onion` are in it.

Comment: @Rechu: the only thing that should be done is enforce that the ingredients have a *unique* name.

Comment: Maybe im stupid but if we have a Recipe with Tomato and Orange in it then the filter will return it and the count will also match 2, even though Onion is not there

Comment: @Rechu: no, since the filter will only accept `Tomato` and `Onion`s in the JOIN, and then we count the number of matches in that JOIN, if the ingredient has tomatos and oranges, then it will filter out the oranges, and the count thus drops to 1, and hence it will not be retained.

Comment: could you paste a sql for it please,  so that I can better imagine :D

Comment: btw. i really appreciate your help

Comment: aaaah okay i got it, yeah you were right, thank you for your help